# Could't open Color Adding Window in Android Studio ..!

Tags: android-studio

I couldn't figure out how to add new color value in the existing colors.xml file using color picker window in android studio. I could not find a direct link to open the color window. The red circled on the right describes from where I open this window, is there any other button ??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Select color

2.Click on add new resource

3.In dropdown select New color value

4.write your name

5.click Ok

[image]

**EDIT:-** It is possible from android-studio 3.4 . There is an option called resource manager

[image]

Comment: Actually what I meant to say was if i had to define a new color value then how can I open this resources window ..is there any other clickable button on the toolbar or every time I had to go to my activity.xml file and from there I had to select background and then this windows will open... The question is how can I open this RESOURCES window ???

Comment: Actually mine is 3.3, running on stable...that's why couldn't find it...

Comment: android studio 3.4 beta 5 is pretty stable and faster for me than 3.3 so I switched to it .

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the color option below the drawable option, click on it and you will get your color selection folder and also check your android studio version

Comment: Actually what I meant to say was if i had to define a new color value then how can I open this resources window ..is there any other clickable button on the toolbar or every time I had to go to my activity.xml file and from there I had to select background and then this windows will open... The question is how can I open this RESOURCES window ?...any other method ???